# Create a li with a span in it AND text

Tags: pug

I want to do something very simple in pug. I wish to generate the following HTML:

```
<li><span class="blah"></span> Some text</li>
```

I don't know what pug syntax I need for this. For example I've tried:

```
li()
    span(class="blah")
    Some text
```

As well as

```
li() Some text
    span(class="blah")
```

Thanks

Comment: The [Pug documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html) has several clear examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [a codepen](https://codepen.io/graham-sportsmgmt/pen/KEjPEd) that shows this live.  Remember to use inspect to see the underlying source code.

This pug:

```
ul
  li
    span.blah
    .
      Some text
```

or this pug:

```
ul
  li
    span.blah
    | Some text
```

Produces this output:

```
<ul>
  <li><span class="blah"></span>Some text</li>
</ul>
```